# Enable threading in Alpine?

Tags: email

I'm setting up Alpine with 10.10 with my gmail account. However, I am having difficulty setting up the threaded view of email (as in gmail). At setup, and in the config menu, I have selected the threading display style to "show-thread-structure." Nonetheless, I get a normal view of email in my inbox, with individual emails displayed separately even if they belong to the same thread.

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In alpine's setup (Main - Settings -> Config).

You may need to pick a "Threading Display Style".  I'm not sure what the default is, I have 'mutt-like'.

Then, when viewing a folder, hit `$` (Sort) and `H` (tHread).

I remember some issues with gmail and threading, I think that the threaded view in gmail is not dependent upon the "In-Reply-To" header that alpine (and other clients read and write).  gmail's threaded index is more complex, using primarily subject (that is all from memory, it could be out of date).

Comment: When sorting by thread with gmail in alpine, I notice that threads are sorted chronologically by the arrival of the thread's initiating message. Is there a way to sort threads based on the arrival time of the last message of the thread?

Comment: @user001 yes there is a way. basically you just need to *first* sort by arrival time, *then* sort by thread. That is: first, `$ A` (then maybe you need to reverse it with `$ R`). *then* `$ H`